# How can I call the ng-lightbox directive on click in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to produce a lightbox when a user clicks a link.  I'm using this light box code [here](https://github.com/tmayr/angular-lightbox).  I'm working with this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pamoge/1/edit).

I have this code here:

```
<button ng-click="add_overlay()">Button</button>
<div class="lightbox" ng-lightbox='{"trigger": "manual"}' id="lightbox">
  <h1>This is some content</h1>
</div>
```

I thought by adding in the ng-click to call the overlay it would display it on click but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm never to angular so any help in general would be appreciated.  How can I produce the lightbox on click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `add_overlay()` isn't accessible to you outside of the `ngLightbox` directive, so Angular has no idea what that method is in the context of your `ng-click`.

You're also using two versions of the Angular source, 1.2.1 and 1.0.7.

If you look at the angular-lightbox source, you'll see an override-able `defaults` object, such that you can provide the element you wish the lightbox be applied to:

```
var defaults = {
    'class_name': false,
    'trigger': 'manual',
    'element': element[0],
    'kind': 'normal'
}
```

So, set up your button like this, specifying the intended element:

```
<button ng-lightbox='{"trigger": "manual", "element": "lightbox"}'>Button</button>
```

[Here's a working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mFHLNWxsNf9rcAd3GGOu?p=preview).